# How to align text with ylabel in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add a text "a)", "b)" and "c)" in subfigures and align it with the yaxis label.

Lets say we have a simple plot, with variable y-axis tick labels "0.8", "0.08", "0.016". This would increase the distance between ax[i].transAxes=0 and ylabel.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=np.arange(0,1,0.01)
y=np.sin(x)


fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(6,4))
ax[0].plot(x,y)
ax[1].plot(x,y*0.1)
ax[2].plot(x,y*0.02)
for i in range(3):
    ax[i].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax[i].spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax[i].set_ylabel('Sine')
    ax[i].set_xlabel('x')
plt.tight_layout()
abc='abc'
for i in range(3):
    ax[i].text(0,1,abc[i]+')',transform=ax[i].transAxes)
plt.show()
```

Currently I am trying to find the (x,y) position by trial and error to right align "a)", "b)" or "c)" with the ylabel. Is there a better way to do this?

If I try to get the position of ylabel using,

```py
ylbl=ax[i].set_ylabel('Sine')
print(ylbl.get_position())
```

I get (0,0.5), which is not really helpful.

More bizzare is when I do a tight_layout.

```py
ylbls=[]
for i in range(3):
    ylbls.append(ax[i].set_ylable('Sine'))

plt.tight_layout()
for i in range(3):
    print(ylbls[i].get_position()
```

I get values (37.7,0.5), (201.8,0.5), (365.9,0.5). I have no idea what these 37.7, 201.8, 365.9 imply and if I can use them to align ylabel with my text somehow?

Comment: Does modifying the xy coordinates not place the label in the intended position? `ax[i].text(-0.1,1.05,abc[i]+')',transform=ax[i].transAxes)`

Comment: It does. But I have to find it by trial and error. I thought there would be a better way to do it. Such as find the coordinates of ylabel and place the text in the appropriate location.

Answer (score 1):

First, get the y-label text box information, and then use the blend transform method, x is from y-label box info, y is from ax[i].transAxes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.transforms import IdentityTransform
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

x=np.arange(0,1,0.01)
y=np.sin(x)

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(7,5))
ax[0].plot(x,y)
ax[1].plot(x,y*0.1)
ax[2].plot(x,y*0.02)
for i in range(3):
    ax[i].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax[i].spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax[i].set_ylabel('Sine')
    ax[i].set_xlabel('x')

plt.tight_layout()
fig.canvas.draw()


abc = r'abc'
for i in range(3):
    iax = ax[i]
    trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(IdentityTransform(), iax.transAxes)
    bb = iax.yaxis.label.get_window_extent()
    iax.text(bb.x0-3,1.01,abc[i]+')',ha='left',fontsize=14,transform=trans)
  
plt.savefig('output_text.png',dpi=300)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this solves the issue. I have a few more clarification questions. 
1. What is the unit of `bb` called? It would be easier to google it in the future.  
2. How to determine `-3` in `bb.x0-3`? It appears that "-3" is related to the height difference of (before 90 rotation) of capitalized and non-capitalized letters in the ylabel. Is this correct?

Comment: Hi, @user198811, 1. The native coordinate system of the output ; (0, 0) is the bottom left of the window, and (width, height) is top right of the output in "display units". The exact interpretation of the units depends on the back end. For example it is pixels for Agg and points for svg/pdf. from https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html

Comment: 2. -3 is obtained by a simple test. First, it is set to 0 and increased or decreased by a certain offset according to the display results.